# Unable to connect to Azure DevOps from Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-logic-apps

I’m trying to queue Azure DevOps pipeline from Azure Logic App. When I create workflow, the connection is configured correctly without any issue. However, the project dropdown list is unable to populate team project and same as build definition id dropdown list. The organization dropdown list is populated correctly. I do have team project administrator to the team project, and do have logic app contributor. I'm also able to get list of team project from this organization using REST-API. Here is an error I got:

```
Could not retrieve values. Error code: ‘Unauthorized’, Message: ‘TF400813: The user ‘573f1013-71ca-6a2f-ac35-ba1bef678b59’ is not authorized to access this resource.
Azure DevOps ActivityId: 0ba5ef8c-4ac4-4810-bf92-7835ca5bf444
Details: TF400813: The user ‘573f1013-71ca-6a2f-ac35-ba1bef678b59’ is not authorized to access this resource.
clientRequestId: eae306a3-f638-424b-96e5-579a70c9dcf7’. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is ‘F6A975D5-74AA-41E3-9DCA-70A508139387’.
```

Comment: Same issue is being discussed @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/522372/unable-to-connect-to-azure-devops-from-azure-logic.html

Answer (score 1):

> Error code: ‘Unauthorized’, Message: ‘TF400813: The user ‘573f1013-71ca-6a2f-ac35-ba1bef678b59’ is not authorized to access this resource. Azure DevOps ActivityId: 0ba5ef8c-4ac4-4810-bf92-7835ca5bf444

According to the error message, it may be that the account you logged in in the Queue a build action selected the wrong domain (AAD directory).

You can try the following steps to sign in the account again in the queue a build action.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Navigate to this user Profile URL: [https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=zh-CN&campaign=o~msft~old~vsts~profile](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=zh-CN&campaign=o%7Emsft%7Eold%7Evsts%7Eprofile)

Then you could select the correct AAD directory.

Step2: Sign in your account to Azure DevOps in Azure Logic App again.

You need to check if the domain is correct.

[image]